# member-wise operations on two dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, max

How would you implement operations like element-wise `max`, `min`, `avg`, `+`, etc. for dictionaries?

As an example:

```
def max_dict(d1, d2):
    ''' @return the maximum member value for each key
    >>> a = {3: 4, 4: 7}; b = {3: 5, 4: 6}; max_dict(a, b)
    {3: 5, 4: 7}
    '''
    out = {}
    for (k, v) in d1.iteritems():
        out[k] = max(v, d2[k])
    return out
```

Is this a sensible way to do it? Is there some built-in function to simplify this? Should `+`, `avg`, etc. be implemented similarly?

(The [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and the [library reference](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) did not contain obvious answers)

Comment: It's unclear to me what the constraints are - for example, in your max_dict implementation, extra keys in d2 are ignored, though that isn't specified in your doc. Do you want exeptions if the types don't line up ("hat" + 3, etc.)? I doubt there's a builtin funtion to do what you want because the answer to these questions will be case-specific

Comment: @en_Knight: the above was an example implementation which should be handled with care. If it were to be implemented in a library, it would be cool if it took a single value if only one existed and apply the operation if there were several. This should be the equivalent of a `list`'s `max` etc functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is generalizable to an arbitrary number of dicts, any function you can apply to a list, and dicts with different keys:

```
def agg_dicts(func, *args):
    keys = []
    for d in args:
        keys += list(d.keys())
    keys = set(keys)

    out = {}
    for key in keys:
        vals = [d[key] for d in args if key in d.keys()]
        out[key] = func(vals)

    return out

from numpy import mean

a = {'one':1, 'two':4, 'four':2}
b = {'one':2, 'two':2}
c = {'two':4, 'four':2, 'five':5}

dict_min = agg_dicts(min, a, b, c)
dict_max = agg_dicts(max, a, b)
dict_avg = agg_dicts(mean, a, b, c)
dict_sum = agg_dicts(sum, a, b, c)

dict_max
{'four': 2, 'one': 2, 'two': 4}

dict_min
{'five': 5, 'four': 2, 'one': 1, 'two': 2}

dict_max
{'four': 2, 'one': 2, 'two': 4}

dict_avg
{'five': 5.0, 'four': 2.0, 'one': 1.5, 'two': 3.3333333333333335}

dict_sum
{'five': 5, 'four': 4, 'one': 3, 'two': 10}
```

Comment: It would probably be good to add in a flag for what to do when a key isn't in all dicts too: drop it or use the ones that are there, as the code already does.

Comment: Those `d.keys()` calls are redundant, and they're a performance disaster on Python 2. Also, you can just make `keys` a set from the start and `union` the dicts into it, like so: `keys = set().union(*args)`.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this a sensible way to do it?

Yeah. I'd probably use a dict comprehension, but the loop works fine.

> Is there some built-in function to simplify this?

No.

> Should `+`, `avg`, etc. be implemented similarly?

You can take the function to apply as an argument:

```
def dict_elementwise(func, d1, d2):
    return {k: func(d1[k], d2[k]) for k in d1}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
d1 = {1:2, 3:4}
d2 = {1:-8, 3:10}
print {k:min(v, d2[k]) for k,v in d1.items()}
```

This uses Python's [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) syntax.

If the dictionaries have distinct keys:

```
d3 = {1:-8, 3:10}
print {k:min(v, d3[k]) for k,v in d1.items() if k in d3}
```

will find produce values that are the intersection of d1 and d3's keys.

So, generically:

```
def map_values_for_keys(func, d1, d2):
    """
    Return a dictionary of k:func(d1[k], d2[k]) for each key k
    defined in both dictionaries d1 and d2.        
    """
    return {func(v, d2[k]) for k,v in d1.items() if k in d2}
```

... although, to be honest, I actually prefer not defining a function for this case since dictionary comprehensions are both simple to read (with practice) and unambiguous to the reader.